# Load https site in iframe on http site

Tags: http, iframe, ssl, https, encryption

We want to load a page of our platform into an iframe on a client site. Our platform contains a SSL certificate and runs always on HTTPS. The client's site runs on HTTP.

The URL that get's loaded into the iframe contains URL params for the name of the user. Are these url parameters send encrypted because the site in the iframe is HTTPS or are they accessible because the the parameters are created on the client HTTP site?

Short example:
Client site (HTTP) loads iframe with url "https://oursite.com/?firstname=Bob&lastname=Forrest". Are the URL parameters encrypted when they are transferred to the iframe site?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL parameters will get encrypted. SSL sits between the HTTP and TCP layers, so the browser will first establish a TCP connection to the server before any data is exchanged. All data (including the request with the URL parameters) will be encrypted.

It is still generally advised to not pass sensitive information in the URL, as it will most likely get stored in plain text in the server logs.